# using function pointers to update value in a sequence?

Tags: c

I am using stack to make a map function, also the struct seq are opaque structures so I can't really use that. I just don't understand why my item in the struct sequence doesn't update with new values
sequence_item_at: is a function that gets the specific item in the stack based on its index
and sequence_length finds the length of that stack

```
void sequence_map(struct sequence *seq, int (*func)(int)) {
  int length = sequence_length(seq);
  int i =0;
  while(i < length){
    int item = sequence_item_at(seq,i);
    int l = func(item);
    item = l;
    i++;
  } 
}
```

Comment: It is because there are no statements to write `l` to `seq`. You will need something like `sequence_item_set_at(seq,i,l);` instead of meaningless `item = l;`, i guess.

Comment: @MikeCAT ohh ,, thank you that makes so much more sense